# jQuery toggle && this issue

Tags: jquery, toggle, this

How can I toggle #editbox div while #plus is clicked? I have multipe #boxt && #editfield  fields. I can make it works only for first div.

boxt is visible
editbox is hidden

```
<div id="boxt">
<div id="editbox"></div>
<span id="plus" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>

<div id="boxt">
<div id="editbox"></div>
<span id="plus" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
```

... etc like 10x

I was trying something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#boxt').click(function(){
   $(this).find( "#editfield" ).toggle(); 
   });                        
});
</script>
```

Comment: use class not id. ID should be unique

Comment: can't make it, I'm toggling only first or all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can't give many **HTML** tags the same `id` as you did with `editbox` & `plus`. Instead of that you should use `class`, and here is a demonstration:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.boxt').click(function(){
   $(this).find( ".editbox" ).toggle(); 
   });                        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxt">
TEXT ON BOXT 1
<div class="editbox">Text on EDITBOX 1</div>
<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plus"></span>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="boxt">
TEXT ON BOXT 2
<div class="editbox">Text on EDITBOX 2</div>
<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plus"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that what I was looking for. Btw, why it wasn't working with ID's, but with class it do work?

Comment: @riten Beacause you gived same `id` to diffrent element, for example you gived the id `boxt` the to first `div` & to the second `div`, this will not work, the `id` must be unique, and this is not the purpose of the `id` attribute. However if you define a `class`, you can give it to as much tags as you want